# How to copy UITableViewCell label to UILabel in nextView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uilabel, nslog

I just want to copy UITableViewCell's label (which is a simple string) into nextView's UIlabel.
I tried creating a string property in the nextView and passing it the cell label, 
but it doesn't work.
I'm getting nil in nextView,
why is that? Here is my didSelectRowAtIndexPath Method
in rootViewController.m

```
    -(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        NSString *selLabel =[tempArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        DetailViewController *detailViewCont=[[DetailViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"DetailViewController" bundle:nil];
detailViewCont.selectedLabel=selLabel;        
[self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewCont animated:YES];

      NSLog(@"selected Label %@",detailViewCont.selectedLabel);
    }
```

Last NSlog statement returns the correct string here.

In nextViewController.m

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
selectedLabel=[[NSString alloc]init];

UILabel *label1=[[UILabel alloc]init];
    label1.frame=CGRectMake(5,5,310, 60);
    label1.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial Black" size:20];
    label1.text=selectedLabel;
    NSLog(@"sellabel %@",selectedLabel);
 [self.View addSubview:label1];
}
```

NSLog statement here returns null

Comment: Is `selLabel` `nil`? Is `tempArray` `nil`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete the following line from you `viewDidLoad` method:

```
selectedLabel=[[NSString alloc]init];
```

This is clearing the value you set from the other view controller.

And this line:

```
label1.text=selectedLabel;
```

should really be:

```
label1.text = self.selectedLabel;
```

You setup a property, use it.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the selLabel before the pushViewController statement like below,

```
detailViewCont.selectedLabel=selLabel;
[self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewCont animated:YES];
```

Comment: your missing the code where you assign the label from tableviewcell to the label1. Your initializing the selectedLabel string and assigining it to label1 before even setting it with a value.

Comment: i have tableViewCell label array called tempArray @shyamsundar1988

Answer (score 0):

Move your line `detailViewCont.selectedLabel=selLabel;` before the `pushViewController` call.  Your presenting the viewcontroller before you assign the value.

```
@interface DetailViewController

...
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *selectedLabel;

@end

@implementation DetailViewController
@synthesize selectedLabel = _selectedLabel; // define the instance variable associated with the property

-(void)viewDidLoad {
  label1.text = _selectedLabel;
}

@end
```

Comment: In nextViewController.m isn't selectedLabel a property?  That's how you're passing the label from the other VC?  If so you don't want to assign it to a new string.

Comment: i am not getting you please simplify

Comment: Updated the answer to hopefully clarify

Comment: finally got it...... i just removed

selectedLabel=[[NSString alloc]init];

from viewDidLoad of nextViewController

Comment: everything else is as it is